# Mapping children of children with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following model:

```
class Page{
  List<Version> Versions
}

class Version {
  List<ContentControl> ContentControls
}
```

which i want to map to:

```
 class Page{    
    List<PageVersion> PageVersions
 }

 class PageVersion {
    List<PageControl> PageControls
 }
```

And i have the following code to map Page to Page and map Versions to PageVersions.

```
CreateMap<Models.Page, vitaminW.Core.Entities.Models.Page>()
                .ForMember(p => p.PageVersions, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Versions));
```

This works fine, and PageVersions gets populated.

However, i'm struggling with mapping ContentControls to PageControls.

If i add the following Mapping:

```
CreateMap<Models.PageVersion, vitaminW.Core.Entities.Models.PageVersion>()
          .ForMember(m => m.PageControls, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.ContentControls));
```

i get the following error:

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Page -> Page
vitaminW.Public.Presentation.Models.Page -> vitaminW.Core.Entities.Models.Page


Type Map configuration:

Page -> Page
vitaminW.Public.Presentation.Models.Page -> vitaminW.Core.Entities.Models.Page

Property:
PageVersions
```

Ive looked up MapAfter, but im not sure how to do this with a child of something i already mapped.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated that you have added a mapping for `ContentControl` to `PageControl`

```
CreateMap<Models.ContentControl, vitaminW.Core.Entities.Models.PageControl>();
```

It looks like AutoMapper can't find a map between the two types and fails.